# Convert characters using Python

Tags: python, utf-8

I receive a text file, but some characters on it are not correct.

One example is the text below:

```
ApresentaÃ§Ã£o/ divulgaÃ§Ã£o do curso
```

But the correct text is

```
Apresentação/ divulgação do curso
```

I use the Php function utf8_decode and it works, see example below

```
echo utf8_decode("ApresentaÃ§Ã£o/ divulgaÃ§Ã£o do curso");
result Apresentação/ divulgação do curso
```

but I can't make it work in Python, I try to use

```
my_str = 'ApresentaÃ§Ã£o/ divulgaÃ§Ã£o do curso'
print( my_str.decode("utf-8") )
```

But I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

How I can make this work in Python?

Comment: Can you show the code where you obtain this string? Eg. through opening the said text file.

Comment: I get the text from a csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is the result of decoding the raw UTF-8 bytes as `latin-1`. So just re-encode them as `latin-1`, then decode as `utf-8`:

```
>>> my_str = 'ApresentaÃ§Ã£o/ divulgaÃ§Ã£o do curso'
>>> print( my_str.encode('latin-1').decode("utf-8") )
Apresentação/ divulgação do curso
```

If this is coming from a file you `open`ed in Python, you likely used `latin-1` (or the similar `cp1252`) as the default encoding for `open`. In that case, the correct solution is to provide the correct encoding to `open` so it's decoded correctly in the first place, changing something like:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    my_str = f.read()
```

to:

```
with open('myfile.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    my_str = f.read()
```

so no additional `encode` or `decode` steps are required.

Answer (score 1):

I think the initial text is in iso-8859-1. This will fix it:

```
>>> s = 'ApresentaÃ§Ã£o/ divulgaÃ§Ã£o do curso'
>>> bytes(s, 'iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
'Apresentação/ divulgação do curso'
```

Comment: The text was initially in UTF-8, but somebody (the OP's code?) initially wrongly decoded it with ISO-8859-1.